# Creating Array of Array from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Hey guys am a learner and I have a string which I want to convert to an array

`var myString = 'one,two\nthree,four\nfive\nsix,seven'`

I want to convert this to an array of array like below

`var newArray = [['one','two'],['three','four'],['five'],['six','seven']]`

In my newArray I want to convert the line break in myString to an array and also split the words and put them as individual elements in an array

I hope I see help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on a newline, and then use map to split all the parts on a comma.

```js
var myString = 'one,two\nthree,four\nfive\nsix,seven';
var newArray = myString.split("\n").map(s => s.split(","));
console.log(newArray);
```